# App size has increased 2X after disabling bitcode in XCode14

Tags: swift, xcode, bitcode, xcode14

XCode14 has disabled bitcode and Apple says they won't accept bitcode enabled apps. Disabling bitcode increases the size of our app by 2X. [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size) can only help reduce the app size by a few Mb.

Has anyone faced this issue and been able to reduce their app size without bitcode enabled?

Comment: I am also facing this issue in our app https://apps.apple.com/in/app/phonepe-recharge-insurance/id1170055821. With Bitcode enabled and Xcode 13, the app size was around 189MB and now with Xcode 14 + bitcode disabled, it has shot-up to 342MB. Can someone please help or guide on how to reduce the app size?

Comment: Hi Srikanth saw your solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74142041/9401766).
I am getting this warning: changes being made to the file will invalidate the code signature in.
Were you able to get your app approved after using the above solution.

Comment: Yes. We have released app 2 times to the App Store after the fix Keer. You should run the script on XCArchieve and not on the generated IPA.

Comment: /Users/keer/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-11-08/Camera.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app
This is where I do the stripping Srikanth?
Can you give me the exact path in which you do it?
I have followed the exact procedure as mentioned in your answer.
Could you shed some light on where to run the script because the .xcarchive doesn't have the .app

Comment: You have mentioned “Camera.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app”. The path where you are trying to do this is correct.

Comment: Thanks!
Have you raised this with apple?
This is a temporary work around at best so maybe we can try raising this. We have started a mail thread and would probably be mentioning this difference in size to them as well. [Note: I have given you a connection request on LinkedIn to discuss further about the issue if possible please accept it]

Comment: Did you have any issues because of this in the crash reporting? That is are there any issues while symbolicating the crashes or anything else?

Comment: No, we did not find any issues in Crash reporting. Things look fine @Keer.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has suggested to enable the `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT, STRIP_STYLE, and STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS` in Xcode build settings.

We didn't enable `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT` and thus the symbols were not stripped and we faced the above issue even when bitcode was disabled.

After setting `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT` to yes the app size was back to normal.

Comment: Where did Apple suggest this? The reason I ask is that the default value for a target is No, while the default value for a project is Yes